# Generate signal sampled with noise

Tags: python, numpy, sampling, adc

To be able to measure the performance of my Analog to digital converter, I would like to make arbitrary signal sampled and normalized. The created signal must have a noise with an rms value and I have to plot the spectral power density of the signal.

So I wrote this code (I do not know if it's ok I'm a beginner) and I would like to know why I visualize nothing on the figure drawn.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib notebook

StopTime = 0.01
N = 1024  
Te = 1.0
Fe = 1.0/Te
t = np.arange(0,Te,StopTime-Te)
f = Fe/2
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t*N)
plt.plot(x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what you (inadvertently) told matplotlib to do.

```
>>> x
array([], dtype=float64)
```

`x` is an empty array, so plotting it plots nothing. It's empty because `t` is also an empty array.  I'm not sure what your parameters are, but `arange` should generally be used only with integer values, and the step (third parameter) should be smaller than the stopping value (second parameter).  For generating a sequence of floats, `np.linspace` is better.

Fixing that (and putting signal generation in terms of sampling frequency, since I'm not sure what your parameters are), code to generate a signal with noise is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

## Parameters used
StopTime = 0.5 # End of signal 
Fs = 1024 # Sampling rate
f = 30     # Frequency of simulated signal

## Generate sample times
t = np.linspace(0,StopTime, StopTime*Fs)

## Generate signal
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*t*f)

## Add noise to signal
noise = np.random.randn(len(x))
print('rms noise value:', sqrt(mean(randn(10000)**2)))
xn = x + noise

plt.plot(t, x)
plt.plot(t, xn)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Khadysr, You're welcome.  If the answer is helpful please also upvote or accept it.